# Bower install downgrades my package

Tags: bower, ember-cli

Every time I install a new bower package on my Ember CLI pack, I got

```
Missing bower packages: 
Package: ember
  * Specified: 1.11.0
  * Installed: 1.10.0
```

then I run `bower install ember#1.11.0`.

```
Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
    1) ember#1.10.0 which resolved to 1.10.0 and is required by test-addon 
    2) ember#>= 1.8.1 < 2.0.0 which resolved to 1.11.0 and is required by ember-data#1.0.0-beta.16 
    3) ember#> 1.5.0-beta.3 which resolved to 1.11.0 and is required by ember-resolver#0.1.15 
    4) ember#>=1.4 <2 which resolved to 1.11.0 and is required by ember-cli-shims#0.0.3 
    5) ember#1.11.0 which resolved to 1.11.0Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

I choose 5 (Why this hassle if I explicit added the desired version), then it works again.

But next time if I install a new bower package, I have to do it again.

**node** 0.12.1

**bower** 1.3.12

**emvber cli** 0.2.2

Comment: have you done a `bower cache clean` recently?

Comment: no, i'm not. I will try it, maybe it helps. ty

Comment: Have you tried prefixing your choice with `!` as advised to persist it? I.e. `!5`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `-F` flag to force to use latest version:

```
bower install -F
```

(see [docs](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install))

In this case bower didn't asking anything about versions.